# How to Format numbers in a column as per currency standards using excel vba?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to format all cells of a column. The data is a number and I want to add a decimal from left keeping only two digits after that. Then format it as per currency standards. For eg:

```
Data:       Output:
10000       100.00
112233      1,122.33
123456789   1,234,567.89
```

The requirement is normal and output is in italics.

Comment: Use the [*Macro Recorder*](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/automate-tasks-with-the-macro-recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b) and do it manually once then look in the VB Editor how that code looks like. If that doesn't solve your question show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 4):

The following will format a given column as Currency:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00"
```

Answer (score 2):

Macro recorder is a bit dangerous in this case, because if you use it, your code would look like this (from the other answer):

`Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00"`

However, this is only ok in UK. If you want to write code, which formats currency based on the local settings of the PC, then it is a good idea to use the currency there:

`Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Style = "Currency"`

Then a UK person would get pounds format and a US one dollars.